# Will Optimized (armv7) keep armv6 hardware users from being able to download an app from the AppStore?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, xcode4, ipod-touch

If not, what happens when say an iPhone 3G user downloads an Optimized armv7 app?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm curious about what you mean when you say optimized.  On what level, with what tools?  If (hypothetically, I don't really know) the two versions have different numbers or sizes or names of registers, it might break compatibility to optimize on that level, but I'm sure the instruction sets are backwards compatible.

Comment: Optimized(armv7) and Standard (armv6 armv7) are the two options in Xcode 4.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is compiled for `armv7` only, the app will not run on an `armv6` device like an iPhone 3G.

You should compile your app as `Standard (armv6 armv7)`. This way it will run on all devices, and it will still be optimised for `armv7` devices. This means that `armv7` devices will see no performance difference between `Standard (armv6 armv7)` and `Optimized (armv7)`, and older `armv6` devices will be able to run the app.

Comment: Is this done with a fat binary?  Why is it even an option if `Standard` supports arm6, and is also optimized for arm7?

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.

Comment: The only thing that gets 'Optimized' when you use the `Optimized` build is the file size.

Answer (score 0):

Apple will probably disapprove the App if you haven't flagged it accordingly (in Info.plist) to only run on 3rd generation and above devices if you only build for the ARMv7 architecture. So the question is moot, it should be:

**How to disallow downloads of my ARMv7 app on ARMv6 devices to get my app approved?**

They way to do that I believe is to specify that your app requires OpenGL ES 2.0.

This image shows you the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities setting at the bottom (opengles-2):
[image]

The image is [courtesy of this blogpost](http://meachware.blogspot.com/2010/08/infoplist-cheat-sheet.html).